# I have an error like this "Missing ; before statement" error on line 44

Tags: node.js

```
if(edatevalue=="") // **checking if edatevalue is blank**
{
  edatevalue = now; // **set edatevalue to now time**
}
else
{
  edate = edatevalue; // **assign edatevalue to edate variable**
}

if(sdatevalue=="")   // **check if sdatevalue is blank**
{
  sdatevalue=0;   // **assign 0 to sdatevalue**
}
else
{
  sdate = sdatevalue; // **assign sdatevalue to sdate variable**
}
var partmsg=""; // **create variable partmsg as blank**

if(sdate==0) // **check if sdate is = 0**
{
  partmsg = "where timestamp between " + sdate " and " + edate; // **create string in variable partmsg**
}

var query = "";

if(topic=="submit")
{
  query = "select * from energymonitoring limit 10 ";
  query = query+partmsg;
}

var msg1 = {topic:query};
return msg1;
```

i am trying to troubleshoot the **"missing ; before statement"** on line `"partmsg = "where timestamp between " + sdate " and " + edate;"`

Edit: I have since then amended accordingly to @Ken Lee's example.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be conditions where your edate and/or sdate is not defined.

Hence, please amend like this:

```
if(edatevalue=="") // **checking if edatevalue is blank**
{
  edatevalue = now; // **set edatevalue to now time**
  edate = edatevalue; // **assign edatevalue to edate variable**

}
else
{
  edate = edatevalue; // **assign edatevalue to edate variable**
}

if(sdatevalue=="")   // **check if sdatevalue is blank**
{
  sdatevalue=0;   // **assign 0 to sdatevalue**
  sdate = sdatevalue; // **assign sdatevalue to sdate variable**

}
else
{
  sdate = sdatevalue; // **assign sdatevalue to sdate variable**
}

var partmsg=""; // **create variable partmsg as blank**

if(sdate==0) // **check if sdate is = 0**
{
  partmsg = "where timestamp between " + sdate " and " + edate; // **create string in variable partmsg**
}
```

Comment: I have amended accordingly but it still shows error "missing ; before statement"

Comment: Edit the original question, do NOT try and add code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have solved the issue, I was missing a "+" symbol between sdate and " and "

```
if(edatevalue=="") // **checking if edatevalue is blank**
{
  edatevalue = now; // **set edatevalue to now time**
}
else
{
  edate = edatevalue; // **assign edatevalue to edate variable**
}

if(sdatevalue=="")   // **check if sdatevalue is blank**
{
  sdatevalue=0;   // **assign 0 to sdatevalue**
}
else
{
  sdate = sdatevalue; // **assign sdatevalue to sdate variable**
}
var partmsg=""; // **create variable partmsg as blank**

if(sdate==0) // **check if sdate is = 0**
{
  partmsg = "where timestamp between " + sdate + " and " + edate; // **create string in variable partmsg**
}

var query = "";

if(topic=="submit")
{
  query = "select * from energymonitoring limit 10 ";
  query = query+partmsg;
}

var msg1 = {topic:query};
return msg1;
```